# How to convert with Ruby accented characters in HTML special entities

Tags: ruby, utf-8, rubygems, htmlspecialchars

How can I do this on Ruby?

```
puts some_method("ò")
# => "&ograve;"
```

In other words convert an accented character like `ò` to his HTML version: `&ograve;`

I tried like this:

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'htmlentities'
require 'unicode'

coder = HTMLEntities.new
string = "Scròfina"
puts coder.encode(string, :named)
```

but what I get this (from: http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) :

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/htmlentities-4.2.0/lib/htmlentities/encoder.rb:85:in `unpack': malformed UTF-8 character (expected 2 bytes, given 1 bytes) (ArgumentError)
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/htmlentities-4.2.0/lib/htmlentities/encoder.rb:85:in `encode_decimal'
 from (eval):2:in `encode_extended'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/htmlentities-4.2.0/lib/htmlentities/encoder.rb:18:in `encode'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/htmlentities-4.2.0/lib/htmlentities/encoder.rb:18:in `gsub!'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/htmlentities-4.2.0/lib/htmlentities/encoder.rb:18:in `encode'
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/htmlentities-4.2.0/lib/htmlentities.rb:74:in `encode'
 from unicode_pleasure.rb:8
```

Thank you for your time!

- Leonardo

Comment: Just tested your example with htmlentities 4.0.0 and everything works fine. Not much help, I know. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had explicitly set the $KCODE to make your example work. Also, make sure your source file is *actually encoded as UTF-8*!

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'htmlentities'
require 'unicode'
$KCODE = 'UTF-8'
coder = HTMLEntities.new
string = "Scròfina"
puts coder.encode(string, :named)
```

Comment: It Works! Thank You Jonathan!
(I can't vote you up cause I have less then 15 reputation :-(

Comment: named parameter was what did the difference to me. Thanks.